Not able to subscribe to a platform event from Workbench
I'm trying to subscribe to a platform event in a Developer sandbox with the use of workbench (API 58.0). The use of Streaming API is enabled in setup.
Via the queries -> Streaming Push Topic
I am getting below error -
Could not load Push Topics. Ensure the both the REST and Streaming APIs are enabled for this organization.


Does this answer your question? Streaming Push Topics - Could not load Push Topics

Hi check below permission to exceute the  Push Topics.
Profile==> System Permission==>

API Enabled
Send Custom Notifications enabled (Optional)

Steup - User Interface --Enable Streaming API enabled
